# NHibernate Stored procedure mapping properties on complex object

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a SQL stored procedure which Im trying to use to load a collection of entities. My entities look like this

```
public class Person
{ 
       public virtual int Id {get;set;}
       public virtual string Name {get;set;}
       public virtual Colour FavoriteColour {get;set;}
}

public class Colour
{
       public virtual int Id {get;set;}
       public virtual string Name {get;set;}
}
```

My stored procedure looks more or less like this:

```
Create Procedure getAllPersons
AS
     SELECT
            p.Id as PersonId,
            p.Name as PersonName,
            c.Id as ColourId,
            c.Name as ColourName
     FROM
            Person p JOIN Colour c
      p.ColourId = c.Id
```

My mapping looks like this

```
<class name="Person">
  <id name="Id">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <property name="Name" />
  <many-to-one name="FavoriteColour" class="Foo, Colour" column="ColourId"/>
</class>

<sql-query name="getAllPersons">
    <return class="Person">
        <return-property name="Id" column="PersonId"/>
        <return-property name="Name" column="PersonName"/>
        <return-property name="FavoriteColour">
            <return-column name="ColourId"/>
        </return-property>
    </return>
    exec getAllPersons
</sql-query>
```

I want to know how I can map the colourName column that comes our of my proc to the FavoriteColour.Name property on my Person entity so that
the FavoriteColour object on Person is populated with both its Id and Name properties. Any ideas?

Comment: yeah sorry about that - trouble with the stackoverflow html editor. Should be there now.

Comment: Have you had read of these posts: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/09/18/UsingNHibernateWithStoredProcedures.aspx
http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/10/04/ShouldYouUseNHibernateWithStoredProcedure.aspx

Comment: Thanks Chris, I did read those posts but couldn't find out a way to update the sql-query/return mapping xml to support complex objects. If I include the foreign key in the mapping, it will lazy load n+1 for each related entity even though my stored proc returns the full tree. It might be that I am missing something...

Comment: I am mapping my classes normally using NHibernate, but for optimisation in certain edge case scenarios I am wanting to use a stored procedure to load a collection of entities.